# How can use the /export request handler via SolrJ?

Tags: solr, solrj

I'm using Solr 4.10.

I have enabled the `/export` request handler for an index by adding this to the `solrconfig.xml` (as mentioned here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Exporting+Result+Sets):

```
<requestHandler name="/export" class="solr.SearchHandler">
  <lst name="invariants">
    <str name="rq">{!xport}</str>
    <str name="wt">xsort</str>
    <str name="distrib">false</str>
  </lst>
  <arr name="components">
    <str>query</str>
  </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

Now I can use: http://localhost:8983/solr/index/select?.... as well as http://localhost:8983/solr/index/export?.... from a browser or curl.

But, I cannot get it to run properly using SolrJ.

I tried (as suggested here: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_10_0/solr-solrj/index.html):

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
...
query.setRequestHandler("/export");
...
httpSolrServer.query(query);
```

The query now has a parameter `&qt=export`. It blew up giving me:

```
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: Error executing query
```

More search suggested using `SolrRequest` instead of `SolrQuery`, I tried it:

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
...
query.setRequestHandler("/export");
SolrRequest solrRequest = new QueryRequest(query);
httpSolrServer.request(solrRequest);
```

Now I get:

```
java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: gzip
```

Any ideas?

---

---edit---

I found an option in `httpSolrServer.request()` to add a `ResponseParser`. I found 4 `ResponseParser`s. Tried them all, the only one that worked was `NoOpResponseParser`. Now I have the correct results, but dumped as a plain string in a single entry in a `NamedList`. I tried to parse it as JSON, but it's not in proper format. Each 30,000 document, there's a missing `,` !!!!.

I returned back to `solrconfig.xml` and changed `wt` in the `/export` handler from `xsort` to `json`. Now the response format has changed, but it's also not in proper format (data is incomplete) !!!!. And `XML` is not
supported.

I'm truly baffled.

Comment: Is your Solr behind the proxy by any chance? I don't think Solr backend is compressing the output. Can you trace the network request with something like Wireshark? It might give you hints.

Comment: I don't have any proxy. I will try to wireshark it.