# Unable to set up Export Handler in Solr

Tags: solr, cloudera-cdh

I have followed the instructions here for setting up an Export Handler for Solr and I am having issues when trying to retrieve the data:

```
Java.io.IOException: org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: xport RankQuery is required for xsort: rq={!xport}
at org.apache.solr.response.SortingResponseWriter.write(SortingResponseWriter.java:100)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.writeResponse(SolrDispatchFilter.java:813)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:437)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:211)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrHadoopAuthenticationFilter$2.doFilter(SolrHadoopAuthenticationFilter.java:394)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:589)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(DelegationTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:291)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:552)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrHadoopAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(SolrHadoopAuthenticationFilter.java:399)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.HostnameFilter.doFilter(HostnameFilter.java:86)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:620)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: xport RankQuery is required for xsort: rq={!xport}
... 26 more
```

I have set up the solrconfig.xml as is mentioned on this instruction:
[Exporting Result Sets](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Exporting+Result+Sets)
So I have added:

```
<requestHandler name="/export" class="solr.SearchHandler">
  <lst name="invariants">
   <str name="rq">{!xport}</str>
   <str name="wt">xsort</str>
   <str name="distrib">false</str>
  </lst>
  <arr name="components">
   <str>query</str>
  </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

But when I use the following query I get the error stated above:

```
http://big-d-cluster:8983/solr/trading/export?q=*%3A*&fl=id&sort=tradeTimestamp+desc
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

I am using SolR 4.10, and I am not using Sorj so it should work, so I am not duplicating: [Solrj export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540577/how-can-use-the-export-request-handler-via-solrj) or [Issue because user was not using SolR 4.10+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34125644/export-from-solr-unknown-query-parser-xport).

Answer (score 0):

I found out that if the Solr Index has no data, you receive the error above. I populated it, and it worked.